# Pandas: Use index value in apply function over a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I was wondering if there's a way to use index value while using apply over a column of the dataframe. Suppose I have df like:

```
  col1  col2
0    a    [0,1,2]
1    b    [0,2]
2    c    [0,1,2]
```

I want to write an apply function on df.col2 such that it removes the index values from the list in col2 leaving a df like:

```
  col1  col2
0    a    [1,2]
1    b    [0,2]
2    c    [0,1]
```

**The index value may or may not be in the list. But if it does exist in the list it should be removed.** Note that this isn't the actual use-case but similar to what I need. I have

```
df.col2.apply(lambda x: f(x))
```

and in the f(x) I want to be able to access the index value of x if its possible or a workaround. **I know that df.apply() can work on the column values and df.index.map() can work on the index. Is there a method in Pandas that combines the use-cases of the two in one single elegant solution**. Thanks for the help.

UPDATE: the index is an integer value and it will be constrained in such a way that its consecutive whole numbers. The col2 will have a list for each index. I want to check if the index is in that list and remove it from the list if it exists. So lets say for row index 3 we have list [27,36,3,9,7]. I want to drop 3 from the list. The list is unordered

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do the job:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.name in x.col2 and x.col2.remove(x.name), axis=1)
```

With the example from the original post:

```
In [226]: df
Out[226]: 
  col1       col2
0    a  [0, 1, 2]
1    b     [0, 2]
2    c  [0, 1, 2]

In [227]: df.apply(lambda x: x.name in x.col2 and x.col2.remove(x.name), axis=1);

In [228]: df
Out[228]: 
  col1    col2
0    a  [1, 2]
1    b  [0, 2]
2    c  [0, 1]
```

Comment: This seems like a more intuitive response but when I run the code I get all None.

Comment: The earlier version would actually just print a bunch of `None`s (as the result of removing an element is in fact `None`), but the `DataFrame` itself will be updated nonetheless. The updated answer in turn produces a weird mixture of `None`s and `False`s, but it is probably a bit more intuitive though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def name_drop(x):
    x_ = x.drop('col2')
    _x = pd.Series(x.col2)
    _x = _x[_x != x.name].tolist()
    x = x_.append(pd.Series({'col2': _x}))
    return x

df.apply(name_drop, axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: @Fizi, I was under the impression that the index value was an integer, and that you wanted to remove from the list, the element indexed with the index value.  From your question, I gather you want to remove the item in the list that has the same value as the index value.  I'll adjust accordingly.

Comment: You are correct-- the index is an integer value and it will be constrained in such a way that its consecutive whole numbers. The col2 will have a list for each index. I want to check if the index is in that list and remove it from the list if it exists. So lets say for row index 3 we have list [27,36,3,9,7]. I want to drop 3 from the list. The list is unordered

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this, this will not delete the index values from the list but will replace it with 'nan'

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('mno'),'b':[[1,2,3],[1,3,4],[5,6,2]]})
df1 = df.b.apply(pd.Series)
df['b'] = np.array(df1[df1.apply(lambda x: x!=df.index.values)]).tolist()
```

> `Out[111]: 
>      a                b
>   0  m  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
>   1  n  [nan, 3.0, 4.0]
>   2  o  [5.0, 6.0, nan]`